# How can I spam-check 12 years worth of email files?

Tags: email

I have 12 years of historical email files which I need to convert and "clean" i.e. remove all the spam -- there is a lot of spam.

I'm happy to install a Linux-based spam detection system, but I really have no need for all the complexity of configuring MTAs.

Is there a straightforward way for me to pass in a directory tree of email files and have them sorted into spam and ham automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the mailbox on IMAP in some client, with Antispam capabilities. The client can check all Inbox mail, process and move/remove SPAM, and it can left you clean your Inbox.

Do you have the probe?